If Occam's razor supports naturalism over theism, then why was William of Ockham, its author, a theist and not a naturalist?
From Wikipedia:

In philosophy, Occam's razor (also spelled Ockham's razor or Ocham's
razor; Latin: novacula Occami) is the problem-solving principle that
recommends searching for explanations constructed with the smallest
possible set of elements. It is also known as the principle of
parsimony or the law of parsimony (Latin: lex parsimoniae). Attributed
to William of Ockham, a 14th-century English philosopher and
theologian, it is frequently cited as Entia non sunt multiplicanda
praeter necessitatem, which translates as "Entities must not be
multiplied beyond necessity", although Occam never used these
exact words. Popularly, the principle is sometimes paraphrased as "The
simplest explanation is usually the best one."
This philosophical razor advocates that when presented with competing
hypotheses about the same prediction and both hypotheses have equal
explanatory power, one should prefer the hypothesis that requires the
fewest assumptions, and that this is not meant to be a way of
choosing between hypotheses that make different predictions.
Similarly, in science, Occam's razor is used as an abductive heuristic
in the development of theoretical models rather than as a rigorous
arbiter between candidate models.

Did William of Ockham ever attempt to apply his razor to his own theistic worldview? Why was William of Ockham a theist and not a naturalist despite having developed a tool that in principle could support naturalism over theism (or even solipsism over naturalism, as discussed in Does Occam's Razor favor metaphysical solipsism?)?

Many hints in your post: "attributed to..." Parsimony principle, regarding ontology (realism vs nominalism) and not "scientific hypotheses and predictions". "Around 1310, when he was about twenty-three, Ockham began his theological training": see Opera Theologica, 10 volumes. For a theologian, to be a "naturalist" can be not apt...

The "if" in the title is a very big "if". Parsimony is not the only, and hardly even the main, consideration in deciding between worldviews, and one can gerrymander their pet version of parsimony to 'support' whatever worldview they favor. To William, God was, of course, a necessity, so the razor was moot anyway.

Right, in 600 years, maybe people will be wondering why we all believed such wacky things.

@Conifold one can gerrymander any epistemic virtue to support their pet theories. Acting like this is limited to simplicity is ignorant. Anyhow, theism contains everything naturalism contains plus more. So arguably, this is less subjective than people make it out to be.

The simple answer is that Occam did not believe in his razor alone. It's not the only criterion for truth. (And also, it's pretty questionable to claim that the razor favors naturalism over theism anyway)

@DarkMalthorp it’s about as questionable as claiming that the earth is simpler than the universe which contains the earth. Every “natural” thing exists in a theistic worldview. The extra stuff are the supernatural elements

@Syed I'm not sure I understand the analogy-- are you saying that Occam's Razor favors believing only the earth exists out of all the things in the universe, or are you saying that it unquestionably favors theism, or something else?

@DarkMalthorp I’m saying that it is hardly unreasonable (and not privy to much questioning) to think that a sub world that is contained within a super world is simpler than the super world. The earth is simpler than the universe since the universe contains the earth plus many more things. Similarly, everything within a theistic worldview contains the natural universe plus all the supernatural things. So, naturalism is simpler, and the title in the question is not a “big if” whatsoever. Sure, this can all still be questioned, but arguably in a very limited manner

@Syed Yes, I get that. That's why I said "questionable" instead of "false". But that standard you propose would trivially favor soplispsim above all else, as e.g. naturalism asserts that {the universe + me} exists while solipsism only asserts {me}. Occam's razor is usually understood as the simplest axiomatization not the simplest model as a whole. As I argued elsewhere, I still think OR favors solipsism under this standard, but at the very minimum it isn't obvious that it favors naturalism over theism

@DarkMalthorp Yes, solipsism is simpler than naturalism, which is simpler than theism as per Occam’s razor. I would argue that this is less questionable than other epistemic virtues that Conifold alluded to. However, simplicity is not the only thing that matters, and one can argue for other worldviews based on other things like how explanatorily powerful they are.

@Syed I don't think it's clear that the axioms of naturalism are simpler than those of theism, though the model is simpler. If I might make a math analogy Z/2Z is simpler than Z in the sense that it's got fewer elements but its group presentation is more complex.

Since we are talking about Okham let's go for the simplest explanation: if he had been an atheist in his era he would have been killed or shunned so badly he'd wish he was dead.

It seems this line "Occam's razor supports naturalism over theism" needs context. Occam's razor is an application while Occam is a person. To compare the person with the application as similar is a fallacy.
===> the logical proof that shows this fallacy is: Occam believed in God; Occam invented Occam's razor; Occam's razor is used by others to argue that God is not involved; therefore Occam believes God is not involved. ---> Except Occam never used this rule this way.

Over at Christianity.SE I addressed why Occam's Razor does not necessarily support naturalism: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/100303/what-are-christian-responses-to-graham-oppys-argument-for-atheism-from-naturali/100310#100310


Ockham’s razor is a methodological tool.
It discriminates between good argumentation and bad argumentation.
But it does not decide between theism and naturalism.

One cannot discriminate between theism and naturalism solely on the
basis of Ockham’s razor.
First of all one has to weight the arguments
on both sides. This includes to assess the clarity of the concepts,
the consistency of the argumentation as a whole and the explanatory power of
both approaches.

William of Ockham was a Franciscan friar, educated as a Catholic
theologian. He did not agree with Thomas Aquinas concerning every
statement of their theological doctrine. But I do not see any reason
why Ockham should have changed theism against naturalism.



Darn, you mean there is no easy answer to these questions? :-)

@ScottRowe History shows that neither camp could convince the other side, neither by Occam's razor nor by other means.

Yeah, history seems to repeat that every single day. Maybe we should find something more useful to debate, something with actual effects on our lives? :-)

History shows that there is no bigger influence on history than theology.  For instance, if you look at the root of our major technological advancements today, many are based on theological debates, such as Turing's machine, Shannon's information theory, Von Neumann's architecture, Mendellian genetics, and so on.

@yters well if an arms race of theological debate is the only way to get technology to go forward, I guess we just have to grin and bear it. You don't have to agree with someone's theology to use their invention.

@yters Is there evidence that in the absence of theology, there would be no other driving force that led to those advancements? I personally see lots of non-theological reasons that all of those things are valuable.

@DanielWagner I would say I see no evidence in history that in the absence of theology any comparable advances are ever made.  All these great advances in thought, and consequently technology, always come about by consideration of ultimate things.  E.g. Socrates claims he was inspired to become a philosopher by intelligent design, and Socrates is considered the founding father of western thought, which in turn produced most advances we treasure today.

That's like asking: if a hammer is best used by swinging it in an arc, why did the inventor of the hammer use it with a stomping motion instead. (Disclaimer: I just made that up)
We evaluate some tool and determine how to appropriately use it by its own merits. This is independent of how the inventor of that tool used it.
We might consider Occam's razor by looking at the natural world and seeing what sorts of claims turns out to be true and when it's reasonable to believe something. We might conclude that claims are unjustified if they have no explanatory or predictive power, if they explain evidence that we can explain by other claims we already accept without any clear explanatory advantage, if they create more "just so" facts, or if they're interchangeable with other comparable claims (related answer). In this way, we might reject theist claims.

As for why William of Ockham was a theist (i.e. believed a false/unjustified thing, according to the given premise), that's really not that different from why anyone else believes unjustified things. That can happen because of various cognitive biases (if not due to a lack of information or being given false information).
William received religious education starting from elementary school. He studied theology. This is not exactly an environment free from social pressure and dedication to a particular belief, which can heavily influence beliefs. Never mind that we've learnt so much since the Middle Ages. And that was not exactly a time known for treating non-believers well. Case in point: at one point, his commentary was condemned as unorthodox and he was ordered to defend himself before the papal court. Later, he argued that the pope was a heretic and spent the last years of his life living in exile. This wasn't even for challenging the fundamental truth on which their religion was based (he disagreed with the church's infallibility, which seems fairly relevant).
In modern times, there's much more diversity in beliefs and arguments, and it's a lot more acceptable to challenge and disagree with religious belief (certainly not everywhere, and not even everywhere in the US, but at least in a lot of places). If he were born in modern times, I think it's at least plausible to think he might have ended up as an atheist (but obviously this is highly speculative, especially given that I'm not really familiar with his writings).

I guess it's the simplest hypothesis, that he would have been an atheist today.

A person’s belief based on a tool says nothing about the significance of the tool. Almost everyone in the world believes that evidence, for example, is crucial to one’s beliefs. Flat earth and global earth believers both believe they have evidence for their respective positions. The fact that these differences exist does not imply that evidence is a useless tool.
Anyone can gerrymander any tool to support their worldview: that is the (unfortunate) nature of philosophy. Arguably though, because theism contains everything that naturalism contains in its world plus more, there doesn’t seem to be any reason at all for preferring theism over naturalism with respect to simplicity only.
Of course, one can argue that theism may have greater explanatory power than naturalism even if it is less simpler, but that is not what was asked about.

it's possible that some individuals genuinely believe the Earth is flat, the behavior of many prominent flat-Earthers strongly suggests that they are just sophisticated trolls and do not believe in anything like this

Occam's razor prefers theism, because it allows for a much simpler description of reality.  To demonstrate this, let's use Kolmogorov complexity, with the addition that the Turing machine can have access to a halting oracle, a stand-in for a divine being.  A divine being worthy of the name should at least possess the equivalent of a halting oracle.
Kolmogorov complexity without a halting oracle is represented by KC(X).
Kolmogorov complexity with a halting oracle is represented by KCO(X).
Kolmogorov complexity is defined as the length of shortest computer program defined with the reference Turing machine that generates X.
The key point is that having access to a halting oracle makes KCO a superset of KC, within a small constant.  If a program is sufficient to generate X without calling out to a halting oracle, then KCO(X) will be the same as KC(X), within the small constant.  However, if the program can be made shorter by calling out to a halting oracle, then KCO(X) will be shorter than KC(X).  So, within the small constant, KCO(X) <= KC(X) for all X.  Consequently, per Occam's razor, KCO is always the preferred mechanism for explaining X.
Per the Church-Turing thesis, a Turing machine can compute anything that can be performed by natural processes.  Consequently, a Turing machine is an upper bound on the explanatory capability of naturalism.  KC(X) is thus the best possible naturalistic explanation of X.
Since we've seen that KCO(X) <= KC(X), and thus KCO is always preferred to explain any X over KC, then this means that KCO is a better explanation than naturalism for all Xs.
Finally, since KCO is a lower bound on the explanatory capabilities of a divine being worthy of the name, then this means that theism is always a better explanation for every X than naturalism, according to Occam's razor.
In response, someone may say, like Dawkins, that the divine being is necessarily more complex than X.  Consequently, KCO is just hiding the complexity in the oracle.  However, the medievals believed in divine simplicity, which is the divine being is completely simple.  It has a complexity of 0.  Therefore, KCO is not hiding any complexity.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
